# Upgrading from 5.3 to current

Tags: upgrading

Is there a reasonable upgrade path from drupal 5.3 to the current version or should I just rebuild the site from scratch? It's a pretty small site, but it does have a few custom content types, and use tac_lite for role-based security.

These are the modules I have installed:

```
tac_lite
filebrowser
private_upload
role_weights
site_user_list
user_import
cck
views
imagefield
imagecache
token
pathauto
path_access
marksmarty
devel
admin_menu
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there is none. No matter if by "current" you mean 7.x or 8.x, skipping 6 is too much gap, and even upgrades from 6 to 7 are known not to be painless and safe.

You may try to rebuild site's structure from scratch, and then use [Drupal-to-Drupal data migration](https://drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d) module to import your data:

> migrate_d2d provides a framework based on the Migrate API for migrating content from Drupal 5, Drupal 6, or Drupal 7 sites into the Drupal 7 site where it is installed. As of 7.x-2.1-beta1, it requires Migrate 7.x-2.6-beta1 or later.

Comment: @sprugman sorry to disappoint.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upgrade drupal 5.x to drupal 7.x then you have to updgrade it in two steps.

1. Upgrade drupal 5.x to drupal 6.x.
2. and then upgrade drupal 6.x to drupal 7.x.

I have done up-gradation of a drupal website from 5.x to 7.x alongwith thousands of nodes migrated successfully to new one.

Drupal upgrade steps are listed in this link https://www.drupal.org/node/570162. I have followed these steps to make migrate successful. Currently site is running without any error.

Remember, there are some things which are included in core when you upgrade from drupal 5 to 6. Key point is you follow these 20 steps to make it functional.